# Cannot query page details from frontend

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to build an app with all dynamic pages so they can be updated by the logged in admin.  In the db (mongoDB) I have a pages collection with _id, pageTitle, and content.  So far I just have the home page so the pageTitle is home.  I am using express with apollo-express-server on the backend and reat for the front end.

I can add a page and query the page by the pageTitle from the graphql playground, but I cannot query the page content from the front end.

Here is my App.js:

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  createHttpLink,
} from '@apollo/client';
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';

// Construct our main GraphQL API endpoint
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  // Set up our client to execute the `authLink` middleware prior to making the request to our GraphQL API
  //link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/:pageTitle' element={<Home />}>
            Home
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Home.js page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { GET_SINGLE_PAGE } from '../utils/queries';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  const { pageTitle } = useParams();
  console.log(pageTitle);
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_SINGLE_PAGE, {
    variables: { pageTitle: pageTitle },
  });
  const page = data?.page;
  console.log(page);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Denver Judo</h1>
      <p>Just some placeholder text</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

When I got to localhost://3000/home it loads the page and where I concole.log(pageTitle) I get home, but below when I console.log(page) I get undefined.
Here is the /utils/queries.js

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const GET_SINGLE_PAGE = gql`
  query Page($pageTitle: String!) {
    page(pageTitle: $pageTitle) {
      _id
      pageTitle
      content
    }
  }
`;
```

Here is my frontend package.json file as well:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If you need to see the backend files I can add them, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the main gralql api endpoint and now it works.  I was sure I tried this before, but it works.  Here is what App.js looks like now:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';

// Construct our main GraphQL API endpoint
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/:pageTitle' element={<Home />}>
            Home
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```